# Disable all requests in Google Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to disable all forms of request whilst in developer tools in Chrome? The reason being is that whilst prototyping some changes, it can be particularly frustrating if you accidentally click a button or for whatever reason cause a page request that erases all the changes made up to that point.

Answer (score 4):

If you toggle device mode you can set network to offline. This is the same as disconnecting your device from the internet.

Comment: This isn't going to work. The page will try to load something. The point is to prevent it from trying if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One:**

Well, it depends on the web page you're on, but sometimes it helps to disable JS before changing something. Sometimes the buttons and even anchors rely on JS. As I said it depends if the web page needs JS, but it might help.

To disable JS:

- open dev console (F12)
- click on gear icon in the right corner
- disable JS

**Solution Two:**

If it's your own web page, you could create a div which lays over all elements and disable all buttons etc. Only for development of course.

**Solution Three:**

You could also write your own userscript which gets all event and prevent them from executing. With this userscript, you would be able to use it on any web page you want and disable/enable it easily, depending on your plug-in for userscripts.

Here's a working example with some events.

```js
$(function() {
    $('body').click(function(event){
        preventExe(event);
    });
    $('body').dblclick(function(event){
        preventExe(event);
    });
    $('body').keyup(function(event){
        preventExe(event);
    });
    $('body').keydown(function(event){
        preventExe(event);
    });
    $('body').keypress(function(event){
        preventExe(event);
    });
    
    function preventExe(event){
        if (event.preventDefault) {
           event.preventDefault();
       } else {
           event.returnValue = false;
       }
    };
                                   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Hit me!</a>
<input></input>
```

Comment: This also won't exactly work. I'm trying to prevent a page request occurring rather than the javascript that executes some of it. Ordinary links will still fire.

Comment: @Jonathan I checked some plug ins but couldn't find any. What about the div layer? if it's your own page you could easily add a div all over your page and set z-index to the highest layer. Than you will click on this div instead of the buttons, but this requires some work.

Comment: Might be a plugin solution, I don't have time to try this myself but worthy of testing. Though focused elements that are fired by keyboard input would still be an issue

Comment: @jonathan yes you're right. Actually I never run into this problem. If you develop on two screen you can open the dev console in a new window. You won't be able the click something by accident, since it's on the other screen and keyboard input only focuses on your dev console window. This might also be an approach with just one screen.

Comment: Murphy's Law still applies though :P

Comment: @Jonathan You could minimize your web page during working in dev console and than only open the window using alt+tab to show the differences (you won't be able to see realtime updates). Too avoid mouse inputs you could unplug it or throw it out of the window before using alt+tab. Too avoid keyboard inputs...throw it out of the window?

Comment: @Jonathan ok one more serious solution. Write a userscript which takes all kind of events on your page, keyup, keydown, mouseclick etc. With this userscript you can easily apply it to all your webpages and you can enable and disable your script at any time.

Comment: @jonathan  Here is a example fiddle, you could use it as a userscript and add events. http://jsfiddle.net/PKpBN/304/

Comment: Can you concat some of your thoughts to as few comments as possible please. Also the fiddle looks good, ought to be raw javascript though. Maybe provide it as a solution instead of the current one (delete repost) and I will upvote but not select as a solution as yet. The javascript disable idea really isn't relevant at all to the question so it might be worth just re-answering and removing this one.